# nbextensions of jupyter notebook cant shown

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

before using my pc, i try this to my freinds pc, and it worked well. but now, when i try this method again there is an error appear. i use miniconda to install jupyter notebook and nbextension

install jupyter

```
conda install --name base -c conda-forge jupyter nb_conda_kernels
```

install nbextensions

```
conda install --name base -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
jupyter nbextension enable varInspector/main
```

and when open the nbextension, there is an error like this

```
[jupyter_nbextensions_configurator] error loading table_beautifier/main
```